# Python syntax error: invalid syntax on string concatenation

Tags: python, syntax-error, chatbot

I'm new to python coding and working on a small chatbot project.
What is the problem in the last line of code? I'm not sure.

```
favanimal = input("What is your favorite animal?")

time.sleep(2)
print(favanimal + ", I like that choice")

time.sleep(2)
print("One more question, this one is extremely important, so choose carefully!")

time.sleep(2)
petname = input("If you had a pet" + favanimal "what would you name it?")
```

Comment: ```"If you had a pet" + favanimal + "what would you name it?"``` You forgot the plus.

Comment: Can you update this question with a statement of the problem? Are you getting a syntax error? You are missing a `+` operator. `"If you had a pet" + favanimal + "what would you name it?"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `+` after `favanimal` in the last line. so just change it from

```
petname = input("If you had a pet" + favanimal "what would you name it?")
```

to

```
petname = input("If you had a pet" + favanimal + "what would you name it?")
```